# How can I regex specific links from rss content in yahoo pipes?

Tags: text-processing, html

From a RSS content I'd like to remove everything except specified href links

Example:

```
<div class='text'>
<div class="center"> <b><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://domain1.com/html/12345948/howto.pdf"></a></b> </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='text'>
<div class="center"> <b><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.domain2.com/php/8mgfjghf/file.html">file</a></b>

<b><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.domain1.com/78/78.html">78</a></b>

<b><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://www.domain3.com/5k9f"></a></b> </div>
</div>
```

I wish my final output like below:

```
http://domain1.com/html/12345948/howto.pdf
http://www.domain2.com/php/8mgfjghf/file.html
http://www.domain1.com/78/78.html
https://www.domain3.com/5k9f
```

Also, domain names are fixed, meaning if domain4.net is present I do not want it in the output.

Comment: seems i have to state that I want to use the yahoo pipes regex module for the above task.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only need to use regex? This works for the provided example:

```
cat file | grep href | sed 's/.*href=\"//g' | cut -d\" -f1
```